# One-To-One relationship with fluent api. A Hacky way?

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship, one-to-one

EF 4.3.1. I have defined `User` and `Box` entities. Each box may or may not be assigned to a user.
What I'd like to achieve is to have a `OwnBox` property in `User` class, and an `Owner` property in `Box` class.
in Database, I have defined `OwnerId` foreignkey in `Boxes` (`Boxes.OwnerId` has relation with `Users.UserId`).
To define the relationship with fluent api, I have defined the following classes:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public virtual Box OwnBox { get; set; }
}

public partial class Box
{
    public int? OwnerId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my Mapping class for `Box`, I have defined the relations as follows:

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.User).WithOptionalDependent(d => d.OwnBox).
    Map(m => m.MapKey("OwnerId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

But by firing up the project, I got the error:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:  (56,6) : error 0019: Each
>   property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'OwnerId' was
>   already defined.

So I had to tell EF to forget about the `OwnerId` column first:

```
this.Ignore(t => t.OwnerId);
```

Now the project works fine. But I'm still doubtful if this is a good approach and will everything work fine on CRUD operations with foreign key associations.

Comment: Have you tried removing the mapping and just letting EF figure out what you mean?

Comment: Since I'd like to have a one-to-one relationship, and I'm not following conventions, I'm pretty sure it's not gonna work.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the reason why you're getting that is because of the `Map` call.

Comment: You're right. But if I don't map `OwnerId`, EF will not consider it as a foreignkey relation to `Users` table.

Comment: I tried mapping this directly in CSDL and got the following validation error: "Because the Dependent Role property is not the key property, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be *."

Comment: A bit confused! Tested updating a User's OwnBox and seemed to work fine.

Comment: @Kamyar, it's been 10 months since you asked that question. Does the solution you proposed work ok? Have you found a better solution? If so please post as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not one-to-one relationship. In one-to-one relationship the foreign key must be a primary key.

I believe in your scenario the situation can happen:

```
User = { UserID = 2 }

Box1 = { UserID = 2 }
Box2 = { UserID = 2 }
```

Nothing stops you from doing that, but which box should be returned when you do that:
User.OwnBox, Box1 or Box2?

EF can deal with that using Independent Association. It will create foreign key, hidden from your POCO class. You can specify the name of the column using MapKey as you did. However, because you also created a property called OnwerID, just as the column used with MapKey, the EF has a problem as two properties are mapped to the same column.

When you use ignore, the POCO OwnerID property is ignored by EF so that fixes the problem of two properties, however, the OwnderID value never gets saved or read to the database. Because EF just ignores it.

Thanks for your question, I have learnt a lot thanks to this.